# Python extract certain rows

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a csv file named test.csv . It contains certain rows with string for instance "Blue". How can I create a new csv file without the rows containing the string "Blue".
N.B Came to this as the find and replace method doesn't remedy the situation.

Comment: The general/"correct" solution would be to use the/a `csv` module. But could you just look for `'Blue'` anywhere on the line? If so, you could do this very easily and simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `not in`

```
with open(file) as f, open(outfile, 'w') as w:
    for line in f:
        if 'Blue' not in line:
            w.write(line)
```

or

```
with open('infile') as f, open('outfile') as w:
    for line in f:
        for i in line.split(','):
            if 'Blue' in i:
                break
        else:
            w.write(line)
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing other csv manipulations. I would recommend using pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/) which is great for analyzing csvs.

Comment: file means file path .. `'/pah/to/file.csv'`